# Lock answer without deleting

Tags: feature-request

When editing an answer, I sometimes want to lock the answer while I'm editing.

I'm proposing a new feature here : Make posts (answers or questions [without answers on it already]) lockable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be an SE-wide change which you would to rise on Meta.SE. But the system already locks a post while it‘s getting edited, so I don‘t see a benefit here. If you do multi-step edits, you can always delete the post while doing so.

Comment: Agreed and the system is already written with code specifically designed to alert an editor that has started editing the post that another edit has committed to save and requesting the now second (slower) editor  to refresh their session before saving. This request seems to go against the design of the current handling of conflicting edits and would require that all to be reworked to implement this request.